# How to send response from AWS Lambda function to custom Flask app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda

I have created an AWS Lambda function, while uploading an image to S3 it will send it to AWS Rekognition for image analysis. The event handler is returning the response and I can send the notification via email using SNS topic. But I want the response from the AWS Lambda function for my custom flask app. How can I do that?

Comment: You really should provide more information and maybe even some code.

Answer (score 0):

Write a lambda function that subscribes to the SNS topic that send the email. That function calls the flash URL.

Comment: Do you have any example ?